# suspicious entries in /var/log/auth.log

Tags: cron, configuration, raspbian

I just had a question regarding the attached part of my /var/log/auth.log file. (Raspberry Pi 2B, running Raspbian Jessy, fully updated / upgraded)

First of all I got rid of the root user all together, but i seem to see a bunch of log-ins for that user (displaying root and/or uid=0), which seem to be locally, as there is no IP-address.

The second question is, why is there an entry for a session of user smmsp every couple minutes.

[image: auth.log]

Comment: That's cron logs. Check your crontab.

Comment: It is generally preferred to display (possibly redacted) output as code block instead of using screen shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two and the last one are CRONs, which is needed for some automated tasks (depend on what is running on your machine `sudo crontab -e`?

The third is probably you running the `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` through `sudo`.

There is nothing to be concerned about. You can't get rid of `root` user, otherwise you would not be able to do any administrative tasks.